# Twitter feeds against hashtag

Tags: c#, api, twitter

I am fetching twitter feeds against a hashtag but it is fetching only one feed.

Is it true that feeds of 7 days would be fetched only?

Below is my code:

```
public string GetSearch(string search, int count)
{
    string resourceUrl = string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json");

    var requestParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
    requestParameters.Add("count", count.ToString());
    requestParameters.Add("q", search);

    var response = GetResponse(resourceUrl, Method.GET, requestParameters);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow: why would you expect more than one feed from a single search?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's limited to seven days: from [The Search API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search): 'The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.'

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is effectively ensuring that tweets will be returned if they are less than 7 days old. If they are older 7~14 days they are sometimes returned. Beyond 14 days you can consider that you will never receive any of them.

This is the reason why people tend to use a long running Filter Stream. The Filter Stream will send you all the tweets matching some specific criteria (for example hashtags) in live. You will then have to store it in your own database and index them to access it for your application.

Please be aware that if the criteria that you attempt to match represents more than 1% of the totals tweets sent on Twitter you will not receive all of them. At this point Twitter will send you a json response starting with `track` and will let you know how many tweets matching your criteria you've missed.

[More Info Here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter)